# Computing the partition function using the forward-backward algorithm for linear chain CRFs

Tags: conditional-random-field, forward-backward

I'm trying to implement the forward-backward algorithm for a Linear Chain Conditional Random Field, as to compute the marginal distribution over labels for each time step in a sequence. I'm following Hugo Larochelle's (excellent) [course on Neural Networks on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SGZ6BttHMPw&list=PL6Xpj9I5qXYEcOhn7TqghAJ6NAPrNmUBH).

More specifically, he describes how to compute the $\alpha$-table (forward pass) and the $\beta$-table (backward pass) in [video 3.4 on computing the partition function](https://youtu.be/fGdXkVv1qNQ), with slides available [here](https://info.usherbrooke.ca/hlarochelle/ift725/3_04_computing_partition_function.pdf).

In the video he states that it's possible to compute the partition function (i.e. the normalization constant of the likelihood function) $Z(\mathbf{X})$, both from the $\alpha$-table and the $\beta$-table. He suggest making the sanity check of computing $Z(\mathbf{X})$ from both tables, as a test of ones implementation. This is exactly what I'm trying to do. But I get different values for $Z(\mathbf{X})$ when computing it using the $\alpha$-table and the $\beta$-table.

### My understanding of the math

What Hugo calls the "*unary factors*", $a_u(y_k)$, is what other call "emissions". They represent some squashing function, combining (possibly) multiple feature vectors $...,\mathbf{x}_{k-1},\mathbf{x}_k, \mathbf{x}_{k+1},...$ from different time steps. I simply assume that each time step has a single feature vector. The feature matrix $\mathbf{X}$ is $C\times K$, where $C$ is the size of the label space and $K$ is the sequence length, and I assume all $x_{i,k}\in(0,1)$.

So in my simplified case the unary factors are simply the entry in the feature matrix $\mathbf{X}$, where the label value $y_k$ serves as the row index, and the timestep $k$ represents the column index,

$$a_u(y_k) = x_{y_k, k}.$$

The *pairwise factors* $a_p(y_k, y_{k+1})$ are just entries in a $C\times C$ matrix of transition weights, $a_p(y_k, y_{k+1}) = V_{y_k, y_{k+1}}$. Say $C=3$,
$$V=\left(\begin{array}\
\color{red}{V_{1,1}} & \color{red}{V_{1,2}} & \color{red}{V_{1,3}}\\
\color{blue}{V_{2,1}} & \color{blue}{V_{2,2}} & \color{blue}{V_{2,3}} \\
\color{green}{V_{3,1}} & \color{green}{V_{3,2}} & \color{green}{V_{3,3}} \\
\end{array}\right).
$$

The $\boldsymbol{\alpha}$ and $\boldsymbol{\beta}$ matrices are both $C\times (K-1)$. In my code I simply assume they both are $C\times K$ and just keep the last and first columns, respectively, filled with NaN's.

If we write out the $\alpha$ and $\beta$ table calculations for the case of $C=3$ we get the following.

$\mathbf{X}$ is,

$
\mathbf{X} = \left(\begin{array}\
x_{1,1} & x_{1,2} & \dots & x_{1,K} \\
x_{2,1} & x_{2,2} & \dots & x_{2,K} \\
x_{3,1} & x_{3,2} & \dots & x_{3,K} \\
\end{array}\
\right)$.

#### The *forward* algorithm

The $\alpha$-table is,

$
\boldsymbol{\alpha} = \left(\
\begin{array}\
\boldsymbol{\alpha}_1 & \boldsymbol{\alpha}_2 & \dots & \boldsymbol{\alpha}_{K-1}
\end{array}\
\right)\
=\left(\
\begin{array}\
\alpha_{1,1} & \alpha_{1,2} & \dots & \alpha_{1,K-1} \\
\alpha_{2,1} & \alpha_{2,2} & \dots & \alpha_{2,K-1} \\
\alpha_{3,1} & \alpha_{3,2} & \dots & \alpha_{3,K-1} \\
\end{array}\
\right)$.

- **Initialization**: $\left(\
  \begin{array}\
  \alpha_{1,1}\\
  \alpha_{2,1}\\
  \alpha_{3,1}\\
  \end{array}\
  \right) = \left(\
  \begin{array}\
  \exp(x_{1,1} + \color{red}{V_{1,1}}) + \exp(x_{2,1} + \color{blue}{V_{2,1}}) + \exp(x_{3,1} + \color{green}{V_{3,1}})\\
  \exp(x_{1,1} + \color{red}{V_{1,2}}) + \exp(x_{2,1} + \color{blue}{V_{2,2}}) + \exp(x_{3,1} + \color{green}{V_{3,2}})\\
  \exp(x_{1,1} + \color{red}{V_{1,3}}) + \exp(x_{2,1} + \color{blue}{V_{2,3}}) + \exp(x_{3,1} + \color{green}{V_{3,3}})\\
  \end{array}\
  \right)$
- **Recursion** for $k=2$ to $k=K-1$:$\left(\
  \begin{array}\
  \alpha_{1,k}\\
  \alpha_{2,k}\\
  \alpha_{3,k}\\
  \end{array}\
  \right) = \left(\
  \begin{array}\
  \exp(x_{1,k} + \color{red}{V_{1,1}})\alpha_{1,k-1} + \exp(x_{2,k} + \color{blue}{V_{2,1}})\alpha_{2,k-1} + \exp(x_{3,k} + \color{green}{V_{3,1}})\alpha_{3,k-1}\\
  \exp(x_{1,k} + \color{red}{V_{1,1}})\alpha_{1,k-1} + \exp(x_{2,k} + \color{blue}{V_{2,2}})\alpha_{2,k-1} + \exp(x_{3,k} + \color{green}{V_{3,2}})\alpha_{3,k-1}\\
  \exp(x_{1,k} + \color{red}{V_{1,1}})\alpha_{1,k-1} + \exp(x_{2,k} + \color{blue}{V_{2,3}})\alpha_{2,k-1} + \exp(x_{3,k} + \color{green}{V_{3,3}})\alpha_{3,k-1}\\
  \end{array}\
  \right)$

#### The *backward* algorithm

The $\beta$-table is,

$\boldsymbol{\beta} = \left(\
\begin{array}\
\boldsymbol{\beta}_2 & \boldsymbol{\beta}_3 & \dots & \boldsymbol{\beta}_{K}
\end{array}\
\right)\
=\left(\
\begin{array}\
\beta_{1,2} & \beta_{1,3} & \dots & \beta_{1,K} \\
\beta_{2,2} & \beta_{2,3} & \dots & \beta_{2,K} \\
\beta_{3,2} & \beta_{3,3} & \dots & \beta_{3,K} \\
\end{array}\
\right)$

Notice the column index starts at 2, which ensures the $\beta$-table is $C\times (K-1)$.

- **Initialization**: $\left(\
  \begin{array}\
  \beta_{1,1}\\
  \beta_{2,1}\\
  \beta_{3,1}\\
  \end{array}\
  \right) =\left(\
  \begin{array}\
  \exp(x_{1,1} + \color{red}{V_{1,1}}) + \exp(x_{2,1} + \color{red}{V_{1,2}}) + \exp(x_{3,1} + \color{red}{V_{1,3}})\\ 
  \exp(x_{1,1} + \color{blue}{V_{2,1}}) + \exp(x_{2,1} + \color{blue}{V_{2,2}}) + \exp(x_{3,1} + \color{blue}{V_{2,3}})\\ 
  \exp(x_{1,1} + \color{green}{V_{3,1}}) + \exp(x_{2,1} + \color{green}{V_{3,2}}) + \exp(x_{3,1} + \color{green}{V_{3,3}})\\ 
  \end{array}\
  \right)$
- **Recursion** for $k=K-1$ to $k=2$: $\left(\
  \begin{array}\
  \beta_{1,k}\\
  \beta_{2,k}\\
  \beta_{3,k}\\
  \end{array}\
  \right) =\left(\
  \begin{array}\
  \exp(x_{1,k} + \color{red}{V_{1,1}})\beta_{1,k+1} + \exp(x_{2,k} + \color{red}{V_{1,2}})\beta_{2,k+1} + \exp(x_{3,k} + \color{red}{V_{1,3}})\beta_{3,k+1}\\ 
  \exp(x_{1,k} + \color{blue}{V_{2,1}})\beta_{1,k+1} + \exp(x_{2,k} + \color{blue}{V_{2,2}})\beta_{2,k+1} + \exp(x_{3,k} + \color{blue}{V_{2,3}})\beta_{3,k+1}\\ 
  \exp(x_{1,k} + \color{green}{V_{3,1}})\beta_{1,k+1} + \exp(x_{2,k} + \color{green}{V_{3,2}})\beta_{2,k+1} + \exp(x_{3,k} + \color{green}{V_{3,3}})\beta_{3,k+1}\\ 
  \end{array}\
  \right)$

According to Hugo Larochelle's slides the partition function can be computed using the $\alpha$-table,

$$Z(\mathbf{X})=\exp(x_{1,K})\alpha_{1,K-1}+\exp(x_{2,K})\alpha_{2,K-1}+\exp(x_{3,K})\alpha_{3,K-1}$$

or using the $\beta$-table,

$$Z(\mathbf{X})=\exp(x_{1,1})\beta_{1,2}+\exp(x_{2,1})\beta_{2,2}+\exp(x_{3,1})\beta_{3,2}.$$

### My Python implementation

Below is my implementation of the above equations in Python.

Unfortunately the the `compute_Z_from_alpha_table` and `compute_Z_from_beta_table` functions do not produce the same value for the partition function (see output below).

I cannot see where I'm going wrong, I need a pair of fresh eyes on the problem.

I have three hypothesis:

- I have misinterpreted the math.
- There is an error in my implementation.
- Some detail is left out of Larochelle's slides.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```py
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1234)

time_steps = 5
labels = 3

transitions = np.random.random(size=(labels, labels)) 
log_transitions = np.log(transitions)

X = np.random.random(size=(labels, time_steps))


def compute_Z_from_alpha_table(X):
    labels, time_steps = X.shape
    last_time_idx = time_steps-1
    alpha_table = np.empty((labels, time_steps))
    alpha_table[:] = np.nan

    alpha_table[:, 0] = np.sum(np.exp(X[:,0] + log_transitions), axis=0)
    for t in range(1, time_steps-1):
        alpha_table[:, t] = np.sum(np.exp(X[:,t] + log_transitions)*alpha_table[:, t-1], axis=0)

    Z = np.sum(np.exp(X[:,last_time_idx])*alpha_table[:, time_steps-2])
    return Z


def compute_Z_from_beta_table(X):
    labels, time_steps = X.shape
    last_time_idx = time_steps-1
    beta_table = np.empty((labels, time_steps))
    beta_table[:] = np.nan

    beta_table[:, last_time_idx] = np.sum(np.exp(X[:,last_time_idx] + log_transitions.T), axis=0)
    for t in range(last_time_idx-1, 0, -1):
        beta_table[:, t] = np.sum(np.exp(X[:,t] + log_transitions.T)*beta_table[:, t+1], axis=0)

    Z = np.sum(np.exp(X[:,0])*beta_table[:,1])
    return Z


print(f"Z from alpha = {compute_Z_from_alpha_table(X)}")
print(f"Z from beta = {compute_Z_from_beta_table(X)}")
```

**Output**

```shell
Z from alpha = 351.829397003545
Z from beta = 334.09770584094815
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The math was correct, the implementation was wrong. I was summing over the wrong axis, in both the initial step and in the recursive step.

```py
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1234)

time_steps = 5
labels = 3

transitions = np.random.random(size=(labels, labels)) 
log_transitions = np.log(transitions)

X = np.random.random(size=(labels, time_steps))


def compute_Z_from_alpha_table(X):
    labels, time_steps = X.shape
    last_time_idx = time_steps-1
    alpha_table = np.empty((labels, time_steps))
    alpha_table[:] = np.nan

    alpha_table[:, 0] = np.sum(np.exp(X[:,0] + log_transitions), axis=1)
    for t in range(1, time_steps-1):
        alpha_table[:, t] = np.sum(np.exp(X[:,t] + log_transitions)*alpha_table[:, t-1], axis=1)

    Z = np.sum(np.exp(X[:,last_time_idx])*alpha_table[:, time_steps-2])
    return Z


def compute_Z_from_beta_table(X):
    labels, time_steps = X.shape
    last_time_idx = time_steps-1
    beta_table = np.empty((labels, time_steps))
    beta_table[:] = np.nan

    beta_table[:, last_time_idx] = np.sum(np.exp(X[:,last_time_idx] + log_transitions.T), axis=1)
    for t in range(last_time_idx-1, 0, -1):
        beta_table[:, t] = np.sum(np.exp(X[:,t] + log_transitions.T)*beta_table[:, t+1], axis=1)

    Z = np.sum(np.exp(X[:,0])*beta_table[:,1])
    return Z


print(f"Z from alpha = {compute_Z_from_alpha_table(X)}")
print(f"Z from beta = {compute_Z_from_beta_table(X)}")
```

```
Z from alpha = 334.5605817318594
Z from beta = 334.5605817318593
```